# Send an email with AutoIt

Tags: email, autoit

How to send an email with AutoIt? Just need a clean example and explanation, containing:

- to
- from
- subject
- message

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two main ways to go with built in code, _INetMail() or _INetSmtpMail()

Below are the simple code examples from the help file.  If you have any specific questions about how they work or how to implement them not covered by the help file please leave a comment.

In my opinion the _INetSmtpMail() route is more reasonable. Below is some example code of it.

```
#include <INet.au3>

$s_SmtpServer = "mysmtpserver.com.au"
$s_FromName = "My Name"
$s_FromAddress = "From eMail Address"
$s_ToAddress = "To eMail Address"
$s_Subject = "My Test UDF"
Dim $as_Body[2]
$as_Body[0] = "Testing the new email udf"
$as_Body[1] = "Second Line"
$Response = _INetSmtpMail ($s_SmtpServer, $s_FromName, $s_FromAddress, $s_ToAddress, $s_Subject, $as_Body)
$err = @error
If $Response = 1 Then
    MsgBox(0, "Success!", "Mail sent")
Else
    MsgBox(0, "Error!", "Mail failed with error code " & $err)
EndIf
```

The _INetMail() method using the built in mail client registered with windows.

```
#include <INet.au3>

$Address = InputBox('Address', 'Enter the E-Mail address to send message to')
$Subject = InputBox('Subject', 'Enter a subject for the E-Mail')
$Body = InputBox('Body', 'Enter the body (message) of the E-Mail')
MsgBox(0,'E-Mail has been opened','The E-Mail has been opened and process identifier for the E-Mail client is ' & _INetMail($address, $subject, $body))
```

Comment: The only problem with _INetMail() is that it's not hitting the send button. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Send in Control + Space. Outlook hotkey

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send email with AutoIt, you hade to choose Microsoft CDO method. Don't use client mail automation (Outlook, Thunderbird or another one). The principle advantage of CDO, is it doesn't depend of client mail program you use. It's only depend on SMTP server.

You can use the function ***_INetSmtpMail*** in librairy AutoIt Inet.au3. But if you want to control any thing, you can use this user defined function ***_INetSmtpMail*** below :

---

#### UDF Autoit file : ***UDF_SMTP_eMail.au3***

```
;==============================================================================================================
; Description :  Send an email with a SMTP server by Microsoft CDO technology
; Parametere  : $s_SmtpServer  
;               $s_FromName     
;               $s_FromAddress  
;               $s_ToAddress    
;               $s_Subject      
;               $as_Body        
;               $s_AttachFiles (path file to join)
;               $s_CcAddress    
;               $s_BccAddress   
;               $s_Username     
;               $s_Password     
;               $IPPort         
;               $ssl            
; Return      :  On success none
;                On error code+msg
;==============================================================================================================
Func _INetSmtpMailCom($s_SmtpServer, $s_FromName, $s_FromAddress, $s_ToAddress, $s_Subject = "", $as_Body = "", $s_AttachFiles = "", $s_CcAddress = "", $s_BccAddress = "", $s_Username = "", $s_Password = "",$IPPort=25, $ssl=0)

    Local $objEmail = ObjCreate("CDO.Message")
    Local $i_Error = 0
    Local $i_Error_desciption = ""

    $objEmail.From = '"' & $s_FromName & '" <' & $s_FromAddress & '>'
    $objEmail.To = $s_ToAddress

    If $s_CcAddress <> "" Then $objEmail.Cc = $s_CcAddress
    If $s_BccAddress <> "" Then $objEmail.Bcc = $s_BccAddress

    $objEmail.Subject = $s_Subject

    If StringInStr($as_Body,"<") and StringInStr($as_Body,">") Then
        $objEmail.HTMLBody = $as_Body
    Else
        $objEmail.Textbody = $as_Body & @CRLF
    EndIf

    If $s_AttachFiles <> "" Then
        Local $S_Files2Attach = StringSplit($s_AttachFiles, ";")
        For $x = 1 To $S_Files2Attach[0]
            $S_Files2Attach[$x] = _PathFull ($S_Files2Attach[$x])
            If FileExists($S_Files2Attach[$x]) Then
                $objEmail.AddAttachment ($S_Files2Attach[$x])
            Else
                $i_Error_desciption = $i_Error_desciption & @lf & 'File not found to attach: ' & $S_Files2Attach[$x]
                SetError(1)
                return 0
            EndIf
        Next
    EndIf
    $objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    $objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = $s_SmtpServer
    $objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = $IPPort

    ;Authenticated SMTP
    If $s_Username <> "" Then
        $objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        $objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = $s_Username
        $objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = $s_Password
    EndIf
    If $Ssl Then
        $objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    EndIf

    ;Update settings
    $objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update

    ; Sent the Message
    $objEmail.Send
    if @error then
        SetError(2)
        return $oMyRet[1]
    EndIf
EndFunc ;==>_INetSmtpMailCom
;===========================================================================================================
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant of what Copas described. Should send automatically for you

```
#include <INet.au3>

$time1 = _NowTime()
$Address = "" ;To Address
$Subject = ""
$Body = ""
_INetMail($address, $subject, $body)
Local $hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:rctrl_renwnd32]", "", 2) ;Works with Outlook 2013. Class might vary. Use the info tool to be sure. Eg I seriously doubt it will be the same with something like thunderbird.
ControlClick($hWnd, "", "Button1")
```